# How to catch the forms auto-completion events with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, dom-events

I am actually processing the validation of a fieldset each time a user press a key:

```js
uname = document.getElementById('user_name');
upass = document.getElementById('password');
btn_submit = document.getElementById('btn_submit');
    
function verif_champs() {
    if(uname.value != "" && upass.value != "")
        btn_submit.disabled = false;
    else
        btn_submit.disabled = true;
}

document.getElementById('fieldset').onkeyup = function() {
    verif_champs();
}
```

The problem is that my form is automatically filled when using Chrome, so my submit button stays disabled even if the content of the fields is not empty. How should I arrange that? I tried the `onchange` event of the fieldset but it doesn't seem to be thrown by the Chrome's auto completion.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onchange` Event for auto complete data.

```
document.getElementById('fieldset').onchange = function() {
    verif_champs();
}
```